# Pull database info and display to html problem?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, fetch

I'm trying to display the information from the database to the html page but it is only displaying the message "connected successfully". The name of the database is "admin" and the table within that database is called "users". I have no idea how to get past the message and just display the table I have created.

Index page (index.php):

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$query="select * from users";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
    <head> Fetch Data Frome Database</head>
</title>
<body>

<table align="center" border="1px" style="width:250px;       line-height: 30px;">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><h2>Account Record</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <t>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
    </t>

    <?php

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['ID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['username'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['password'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }

    ?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

CONNECTION PAGE (connection.php):

```
<?php
//Include your own values for username, password and     dbase name

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "admin";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,     $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: You connected using mysqli but used mysql in query.

Comment: thank you. Although this helped actually display the table to the webpage, the results from the table haven't been displayed. I changed the query sql to sqli and the while loop to sqli. am I missing anything to actually display the results?

Comment: <?php
 include_once('connection.php');
 $query="SELECT * FROM users";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
?>

Comment: I have changed my coding to the above^^^. This now displays the table, and also the 3 slots for the 3 sets of data I have within the database. still isn't pulling it from the database thought

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all of your PHP into a single block

```
 <?php

include_once('connection.php');
$query="select * from users";
$result=mysql_query($query);

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {


    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['ID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rows['username']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rows['password']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

?>
```

Comment: just tried that mate and still the same result. Just showing the table and the titles without the database info. The name of the columns that I'm trying to call from the database match up as well. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump or print_r $result? Let's verify that data is actually coming through.

Comment: sorry I've never tried that before. could you explain how to check this?

Comment: simply var_dump($result); or print_r($result);

Comment: Ah! Well that indicates that the issue must lie with your connection or your query, since the data doesn't seem to be getting to the page.

Comment: although, when I type the "print_r($result);" it returns "1".

Comment: @you sure you have records in database?

Comment: yes. localhost:8889. Database name is "admin". Table name is "users". 3 records are in the database with an "ID", "username" and "password". The ID is the primary key and has auto increment selected.

Comment: can I ask, see the "$result=mysqli_query($query);" what should usually go in-between the brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that your while loop is not set up correctly. The equals operator will pass the value of mysql_fetch_assoc($result) to $rows so this just wont do anything. Just think that a single equals sign does not mean equal it really means becomes. So rows becomes result. If you have two equals signs you are comparing the two values but this wont help you either. What your really need to do is first set rows to zero then say while the rows are less then the result echo the id echo the username echo the password and add 1 to rows.

So the while loop should look more like this

```
$rows = 0;
while($rows < mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
         $rows++   
   ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['ID'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['username'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['password'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
```

Assuming that $result=mysql_query($query) actually has a value this should work.

If you need to test if your result is good use PHP's array print to check print_r($result); This will echo all the results to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

So I prefer using this method since its a little better than any other method I have tried. Plus I tuck the connection into a class and it makes it soo much easier to handle db connections.

DB CONNECTION Page:

```
class Database
{
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "root";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "admin";
public $conn;

public function dbConnection()
{

    $this->conn = null;
    try
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```

}

Now I create a class for the connection. I usually name it the site name.

```
require_once "db/config/page/location.php";

class localhost {
  // Create conn to db
      private $conn;

      public function __construct()
      {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
      }

      public function runQuery($sql)
      {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
      }
}
```

Note: when you would like to use the connection on any page. 
You can do the following:
EG Index Page:

```html
<?php
    include_once('class.php');
    $lHost = new localhost();

        //calling the users
        $stmt = $lHost->runQuery('SELECT * FROM `users`');
        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>
        <head> Fetch Data Frome Database</head>
    </title>
    <body>

    <table align="center" border="1px" style="width:250px;       line-height: 30px;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"><h2>Account Record</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <t>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </t>

        <?php
        foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user['ID'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['username'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['password'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Feel free to ask me any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your file. Use this file as one first to test.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Selecting Table in MySQLi Server</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'admin';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';
         $sql = 'SELECT name FROM tutorials_inf';
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Note:**  You can test for errors using `mysqli_error()`such as `echo  mysqli_error();` after your select query.